# Problemas con Mi archivo .htaccess y la URL amigable

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

en mi sistemas estoy implementando esto de las URl amigables ya que me parece poco profesional que las URl se vean las extensiones de los archivos y las variables que se están pasando por $_GET, ya logré quitar las extensiones de los archivos mediante el .htaccess bien, una vez que el usuario entra a su escritorio previamente logueado tengo esta direccion:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/usuario
```

aquí mi archivo htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/casillero/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

#Reglas para cambiar las extensiones de los archivos en las URL en los archivos principales
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^registro$ frmregistro.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^login$ frmlogin.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^usuario$ escritorio_user.php [NC]

#Reglas para las URL amigables
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_]+)$ escritorio_user.php?modo=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ escritorio_user.php?modo=$1&cas=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

aquí la barra de menú por donde el usuario navega

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li ><a href="nvafactura/<?php echo $_SESSION['casillero'];?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Facturas <span class="badge" id="facturaspendientes"></span></a></li>
                    <li ><a href="alerta#frmalerta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></span> Alertar</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="rastreo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Rastreo de paquetes</a></li>
                </ul>
```

**¿Cual es mi problema?**
Cuando el usuario navega, por ejemplo le da clic al enlace 'alerta' obtiene esta direccion en la url:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/alerta#frmalerta
```

¡Perfecto! y asi sucesivamente cuando le da clic al enlace rastreo obtiene esta direccion:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/rastreo
```

¡Perfecto! cuando da clic al enlace nvafactura me obtiene esta dirección:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/nvafactura/DT24VZ-51
```

¡Perfecto! porque es el formato que le dí en el archivo `htaccess` y me esta trayendo los resultados de la base de datos ya que a través de ese enlace estoy pasando 2 variables `$_GET`.

¡Perfecto! el detalle está en que cuando el sistema se encuentra en la ultima URL citada y el usuario quiere hace clic por ejemplo en el enlace alerta obtiene esta dirección:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/nvafactura/alerta#frmalerta
```

Y si le vuelvo a dar a rastreo me da la siguiente URL:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/nvafactura/rastreo
```

En ves de darme:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/rastreo ó
http://localhost/test/casillero/alerta#frmalerta
```

Y si le vuelvo a dar al enlace factura me da la siguiente URL:

```
http://localhost/test/casillero/nvafactura/nvafactura/DT24VZ-51
```

Veo que el sistema no vuelve a la dirección base una vez el usuario entra en el enlace `nvafacturas` y me causa un problema en el sistema no me muestra las paginas citadas en los enlaces, como puedo resolver esto ya que he tratado y no he conseguido, leí aquí un post que tenia un problema similar pero no pude resolver mi problema, saludos.

Comment: Éste es el comportamiento normal porque usando direcciones relativas. Entonces cuando estás en "/nvafactura/loquesea", si pulsas a un enlace que va a "rastreo", lo que va a hacer es ir a "nvafactura/rastreo". Deberías usar direcciones absolutas o relativas a la raíz. (aunque seguramente eso no te funcione porque entonces intentará ir a "localhost/rastreo" en lugar de "localhost/test/rastreo". Tuve un caso similar y al final lo que hice fue crear un host virtual que simulara como iba a verse online. ¿Es eso algo que te interesaría?

Comment: Pero me imagino que debe de haber otro método, no se cual, y es el que estoy buscando